# Embed external swf file

Tags: flash, embed, external

I can host a swf file locally with the web page it is embededed in, but if I change the src attaribute for the embed tag in the html file to point to an external link on mediafire.com the content never loads.

Is there anything I need to configure to host a swf file externally to the server which hosts the web page it is embedded into ?

NB: I can  open the media file directly by clicking a <a href> link on my page

```
<OBJECT CLASSID="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" WIDTH="1137" HEIGHT="912" CODEBASE="active.macromedia.com/flash5/cabs/…; <PARAM NAME=movie VALUE="mediafire.com/file/dvtk94k4qyi1w1b/page1.swf">; <PARAM NAME=play VALUE=true> <PARAM NAME=loop VALUE=false> <PARAM NAME=wmode VALUE=transparent> <PARAM NAME=quality VALUE=low>
<EMBED SRC="mediafire.com/file/dvtk94k4qyi1w1b/page1.swf"; WIDTH=1137 HEIGHT=912 quality=low loop=false wmode=transparent TYPE="shockwave-flash" PLUGINSPAGE="macromedia.com/shockwave/download/…; </EMBED> </OBJECT> <SCRIPT src='page1.js'></script>
```

Edit: Here's the html for the page, which is at a different domain to the swf.

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<center><OBJECT CLASSID="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" WIDTH="1137" HEIGHT="912" CODEBASE="http://active.macromedia.com/flash5/cabs/swflash.cab#version=7,0,0,0">
<PARAM NAME=movie VALUE="http://www.mediafire.com/file/dvtk94k4qyi1w1b/page1.swf">
<PARAM NAME=play VALUE=true>
<PARAM NAME=loop VALUE=false>
<PARAM NAME=wmode VALUE=transparent>
<PARAM NAME=quality VALUE=low>
<EMBED SRC="http://www.mediafire.com/file/dvtk94k4qyi1w1b/page1.swf" WIDTH=1137 HEIGHT=912 quality=low loop=false wmode=transparent TYPE="shockwave-flash" PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash">
</EMBED>
</OBJECT></center>
<SCRIPT src='page1.js'></script>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: <HTML>
    <BODY>
    <center><OBJECT CLASSID="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" WIDTH="1137" HEIGHT="912" CODEBASE="http://active.macromedia.com/flash5/cabs/swflash.cab#version=7,0,0,0">
    <PARAM NAME=movie VALUE="http://www.mediafire.com/file/dvtk94k4qyi1w1b/page1.swf">
    <PARAM NAME=play VALUE=true>
    <PARAM NAME=loop VALUE=false>
    <PARAM NAME=wmode VALUE=transparent>
    <PARAM NAME=quality VALUE=low>

Comment: <EMBED SRC="http://www.mediafire.com/file/dvtk94k4qyi1w1b/page1.swf" WIDTH=1137 HEIGHT=912 quality=low loop=false wmode=transparent TYPE="shockwave-flash" PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash">

    </EMBED>
    </OBJECT></center>
    <SCRIPT src='page1.js'></script>
    </BODY>
    </HTML>

Comment: ... in your original question.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you can access the file? Use firebug or Chrome's built in debugger and check the net tab.

My bet is that the swf is password protected, and your clients just cant reach the file.

Comment: this is the file I am linking, can you see it ? http://www.mediafire.com/?dvtk94k4qyi1w1b